# R: creating a named vector from variables

Tags: r

Inside a function I define a bunch of scalar variables like this:

```
a <- 10
b <- a*100
c <- a + b
```

At the end of the function, I want to return `a,b,c` in a *named vector*, with the same names as the variables, with minimal coding, i.e. I *do not* want to do:

```
c( a = a, b = b, c = c )
```

Is there a language construct that does this? For example, if I simply do `return(c(a,b,c))` it returns an unnamed vector, which is not what I want. I currently have a hacky way of doing this:

```
> cbind(a,b,c)[1,]
   a    b    c 
  10 1000 1010
```

Is there perhaps a better, less hacky, way?

Comment: What could be less minimal than c(a=a,b=b,c=c)? You have to specify the names and values somewhere. Or do you want it to magically realise that 'a' is called 'a'?

Comment: Yes that's what I want -- e.g. the `cbind` above does that, and I'm quite happy with its minimality, but I wondered if there was a more straightforward way. Variable names could be long... and I want to save on typing :)

Comment: you want to save on typing, but you obscure your code (if I see such a construct, I get it out of the code asap) and you lose quite some performance when dealing with big and/or many vectors. I'd really think again whether you're not finding a solution to something that can be solved in a different way.

Comment: Why are you concerned with saving on typing within a function?  You only write it once.  I would encourage you to instead focus on execution speed and clarity.

Comment: @Joshua I agree with you in general. I was just bothered by the fact that `cbind()` preserves variable names and `c()` doesn't, so I was checking if there was maybe a simple way to acheive this.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here's a function to do that for you, which also allows you to optionally name some of the values.  There's not much to it, except for the trick to get the unevaluated expression and deparse it into a single character vector.

```
c2 <- function(...) {
  vals <- c(...)

  if (is.null(names(vals))) {
    missing_names <- rep(TRUE, length(vals))
  } else {
    missing_names <- names(vals) == ""
  }
  if (any(missing_names)) {
    names <- vapply(substitute(list(...))[-1], deparse, character(1))
    names(vals)[missing_names] <- names[missing_names]
  }

  vals
}

a <- 1
b <- 2
c <- 3

c2(a, b, d = c)
# a b d 
# 1 2 3
```

Note that it's not guaranteed to produce syntactically valid names.  If you want that, apply the `make.names` function to the `names` vector.

```
c2(mean(a,b,c))
# mean(a, b, c) 
#            1
```

Also, as with any function that uses substitute, `c2` is more suited for interactive use than to be used within another function.

Comment: @hadley: `substitute(list(...))[-1]` can be shortened to with `substitute(...())`

Comment: Shortened, but made even more confusing! (I realise list isn't used, but it conveys the intent)

Comment: @hadley: I have added two functions `nc` and `nlist` to [my `kimisc` package](https://github.com/krlmlr/kimisc), crediting you and this answer.