# How to create a list with names but no entries in R/Splus?

Tags: r, s-plus

I'd like to set up a list with named entries whose values are left uninitialized (I plan to add stuff to them later). How do people generally do this? I've done:

```
mylist.names <- c("a", "b", "c")
mylist <- as.list(rep(NA, length(mylist.names)))
names(mylist) <- mylist.names
```

but this seems kind of hacky. There has to be a more standard way of doing this...right?

Comment: Vaguely related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5042806/r-creating-a-named-vector-from-variables/5043280#5043280

Answer (score 69, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```
mylist.names <- c("a", "b", "c")
mylist <- vector("list", length(mylist.names))
names(mylist) <- mylist.names
```

Comment: There is function to set names: `setNames(vector("list", length(mylist.names)), mylist.names)`.

Comment: It always depends on what you want to archive. I usually like to break up steps to make reading the code easier. R / Splus tends to let you write quite a lot of stuff in one line - which is fine for testing and getting done fast, but bad for readability.

Answer (score 38):

A little bit shorter version than Thilo :)

```
mylist <- sapply(mylist.names,function(x) NULL)
```

Comment: I like it.  One thing to add, if your names are numbers, the numeric values are ignored as names, and just 1, 2, 3... are used.  To circumvent that, try: `sapply(as.character(4:6),function(x) NULL)`

Comment: Beware of using `sapply` inside a function https://twitter.com/hadleywickham/status/434339083871993856

Comment: You can replace `sapply` with `purrr::map` using `mylist <- purrr::map(mylist.names, ~ NULL)`

Comment: However, you then need to use `names(mylist) <- mylist.names`

Comment: Best of both worlds? `lapply(mylist.names, function(x) NULL) %>% setNames(mylist.names)`

Answer (score 9):

Another tricky way to do it:

```
mylist.names <- c("a", "b", "c") 

mylist <- NULL
mylist[mylist.names] <- list(NULL)
```

This works because your replacing non-existing entries, so they're created. The list(NULL) is unfortunately required, since NULL means REMOVE an entry:

```
x <- list(a=1:2, b=2:3, c=3:4)
x["a"] <- NULL # removes the "a" entry!
x["c"] <- list(NULL) # assigns NULL to "c" entry
```

Comment: I would probably use `mylist <- list()` because it more clearly shows you are initializing an empty list. I actually am somewhat surprised that it works with setting it to `NULL`. I assume that `mylist` gets promoted from a `NULL` to a list when you assign to it that way.

Answer (score 1):

```r
vector("list", length(mylist.names)) |> setNames(mylist.names)
```

```r
$a
NULL

$b
NULL

$c
NULL
```

Inspired by [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5688020/how-to-create-a-list-with-names-but-no-entries-in-r-splus#comment6515764_5688126)