# lapply over vector, use values as output list names

Tags: r

I was wondering what the best way is to use the lapply famliy (or plyr) family of functions to take a vector, apply a function to the elements, and return a list whose names are the same as the values supplied in the first argument vector.  So, for example if i do:

```
lapply(letters[1:3], function(x) NULL)

[[1]]
NULL

[[2]]
NULL

[[3]]
NULL
```

I'd like to return, instead of [[1]], [[2]], [[3]] as the name (or rather just plain index) of the list, the letters "a", "b", and "c" as the names of the output list.

I know from here that I can do this ([How to create a list with names but no entries in R/Splus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5688020/how-to-create-a-list-with-names-but-no-entries-in-r-splus)) to create the list beforehand with the right names, but I am wondering if I can do this without pre-creating the list with the right names.

Thanks,
Matt

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`sapply` has a `USE.NAMES` argument that will do what you want:

```
sapply(letters[1:3], function(x) NULL, simplify=FALSE, USE.NAMES=TRUE)
# $a
# NULL

# $b
# NULL

# $c
# NULL
```

As Josh O'Brien notes in the comments--and as you've figured out--`simplify=FALSE` prevents the output from being reduced to a simpler data structure, keeping the results consistent with what you'd get with `lapply` (well, besides the names of course).

Comment: Possibly also set `simplify=FALSE` to make the behavior more consistently like `lapply()`'s.

Comment: Josh O'Brien : I was going to respond with the problem of when I replace `Null` with, say, a string, it collapses from a list to a vector.  Your comment addresses that, thanks.

Comment: Yeah, I'll edit my answer.